# Why can't I put this grid on my button?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I need my buttons to have several pieces of text on them in a specific layout, so I'm trying to put a grid on my button to organize the info.

My problem is that while I can get the unmodified button to appear, the grid never appears in or on top of it.

Here's the .xaml code:

```
<!-- ...other code up above... -->

<ItemsControl x:Name="btnList">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="Green">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Margin="15"
                           Text="Test Text 1" />

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Text="Test Text 2" />

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Text="Test Text 3" />

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.Column="2"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Text="Test Text 4" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Here's the associated .xaml.cs code:

```
    public THINGSelectFlyout()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        foreach (XTHING_IndexItem indexItem in DataStore.Instance.THINGsFoundOnTap)
        {
            Button button = new Button()
            {
                Name = indexItem.cGuid.ToString("N"),
                Content = indexItem.cName,
                Style = Application.Current.Resources["BigButtons"] as Style
            };
            button.Click += THINGButton_Click;
            btnList.Items.Add(button);
        }
```

When run like this the buttons appear (with the default background color, blue) and have the content that's given to them in the .xaml.c file.

As a side note, I am modifying someone else's code and long story short I cannot move the entire button construction into the .xaml file; too many other things expect it to be there.

Comment: have tried making the width and height of the button bigger to verify that you're not dealing with a stretch issue?

Comment: I don't see anything that suggests the button should have the grid on it. Why not just set button's Content to a grid?

Comment: Tweaking the dimensions of the button does not make the grid visible.

Comment: I had expected the Grid in the .xaml file to overlay the button, but clearly that's not how it works. I've been trying to put the grid in the .xaml.cs file but can't get it to work right; I can create a 'new Grid()' and set the content equal to it, but all the resources for modifying a Grid I can find online are all done in a .xaml file and not in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't it just figure that, after fumbling around for hours, the minute I ask for help here I then stumble onto the answer with my next online search?

The grid is best made in the .xaml.cs file, not the .xaml file. Maybe you could get the .xaml to work with a ViewModel, but I'm not making another a new view model when this works just as well.

New .xaml code:

```
<!-- ...other code up above... -->
    <ItemsControl x:Name="btnList" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

New .xaml.cs code:

```
    public THINGSelectFlyout()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        foreach (XTHING_IndexItem indexItem in DataStore.Instance.THINGsFoundOnTap)
        {

            Button button = new Button()
            {
                Name = indexItem.cGuid.ToString("N"),
                Style = Application.Current.Resources["BigButtons"] as Style
            };

            Grid textGrid = new Grid();
            // Define Grid rows
            RowDefinition rowDef1 = new RowDefinition();
            RowDefinition rowDef2 = new RowDefinition();
            RowDefinition rowDef3 = new RowDefinition();
            rowDef1.Height = new GridLength(20);
            rowDef2.Height = new GridLength(22);
            rowDef3.Height = new GridLength(25);
            textGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef1);
            textGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef2);
            textGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef3);
            // Define Grid columns
            ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
            ColumnDefinition colDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();
            colDef1.Width = new GridLength(150);
            colDef2.Width = new GridLength(105);
            textGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
            textGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef2);

            // Set indexItem text
            TextBlock indexText = new TextBlock();
            indexText.Text = indexItem.cName;
            indexText.TextAlignment = 0;
            textGrid.Children.Add(indexText);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(indexText, 2);
            Grid.SetRow(indexText, 1);

            // Set assignment text
            TextBlock assgnText = new TextBlock();
            assgnText.Text = "  Assgn: " + indexItem.cAssignedTo;
            indexText.TextAlignment = 0;
            textGrid.Children.Add(assgnText);
            Grid.SetRow(assgnText, 2);

            // Set owner text
            TextBlock ownerText = new TextBlock();
            ownerText.Text = "Owner: " + indexItem.cOwnedBy;
            indexText.TextAlignment = 0;
            textGrid.Children.Add(ownerText);
            Grid.SetRow(ownerText, 2);
            Grid.SetColumn(ownerText, 1);

            button.Content = textGrid;

            button.Click += THINGButton_Click;
            btnList.Items.Add(button);
        }
    }
```

The only downside to this is I'm not sure how to get put down a * operator to auto-size the row and column dimensions like .xaml allows, but it does what I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

Bind your ItemsControl to a list belonging to your ViewModel:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="btnList"  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Button>
           <Button.Content>
                  <!-- Place your Grid Xaml here -->
           </Button.Content>
       </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Add an `ObservableCollection` to your ViewModel, the collection would be a list of the `DataStore.Instance.THINGsFoundOnTap` type.

So in your ViewModel, add a new instance property:

```
private ObservableCollection<YourType> _items = new ObservableCollection<YourType>();

public ObservableCollection<YourType> Items
{
    get{ return _items; }
}
```

Then modify your view so that you are adding your ViewModel, notice you must set the views DataContext to the view model:

```
var viewModel = new YourViewModel();  //create your view model
DataContext = viewModel;   // set the views DataContext

foreach (XTHING_IndexItem indexItem in DataStore.Instance.THINGsFoundOnTap)
{
   viewModel.Items.Add( indexItem);
}
```

Finally, modify your view to bind to a single item in the ViewModels `Items` collection:

```
 <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Text="{Bind cName}" />
```

You can handle the click event or command whichever way you want.